# ROS Answers SE migration: edge detection

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to write a simple Canny edge detection program in ROS? I have done this in VC++. But i'm not getting the program flow in ROS...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12881/edge-detection/) by [nandhini](https://answers.ros.org/users/1736/nandhini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-02-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll want to use the [image_transport](http://ros.org/wiki/image_transport) library to subscribe to image messages from a camera, and [cv_bridge](http://ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge) to convert from ROS image messages into an openCV image type.

Take a look at the [cv_bridge C++ tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages). The Diamondback tutorial should apply to Electric as well.

You may also want to take a look at the generic publisher and subscriber tutorials to get a feel for ROS in general.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Program flow in ROS is that, it understands the images as a streams of frames (messages) from the camera. You have to process these frames according to the algorithm that you wanted. So these frames coming into the ROS will not be in Mat format for you to use the canny function of OpenCV directly. Hence as mentioned by Ahendrix you have to convert them to the Mat format using cv_bridge and process the frame. Once you have processed it you may want to convert it to ros msg again and publish it to the other nodes.

Hope it helps!!
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-02-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try this example http://code.google.com/p/robocraft-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/ocv_capture/src/ocv_canny.cpp

---

Originally posted by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) with karma: 471 on 2012-02-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First I'd recommend running [this](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html#canny-detector) OpenCV tutorial outside of ROS.

Once you get that working, I'd try integrating it with [this](http://ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) ROS tutorial also mentioned above.

---

Originally posted by [bkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/1731/bkx/) with karma: 145 on 2012-02-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1